# AWS Amplify Modlegen Generate Android Studio Compilation Errors

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, aws-amplify

I tried to use the following model in Android Studio 4, targeting a device running Android 9 / Pie.

I used the last version of Amplify Android, 1.1.1

The generate process succeeded, but the Android compilation process failed.

```
type Records @model {
  id: ID!
  user: String!
  vaccine_name: String
  vaccine_volume: Int
  injection_volume: Int
  bottle_volume: Int
  spray_name: String
  day_counter: Int
  batch_counter: Int
  replace_param: String
  temp_range: String
  location: String
} details
```

```
failed
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
app/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/datastore/generated/model/Records.java
Builder is not abstract and does not override abstract method temp_range(String) in BuildStep
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
cannot find symbol method vaccineName(String)
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for
```

Comment: I succeed to generate only when I used the screamer for all the fields, do I need to implement methods with no screamer by my self ?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Can you report this at https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/new ?

Comment: Reported https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/696